# can't debug android application after some code changes

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I am not able to debug application.The app runs when i click on debug button,but the debugger is not attached and it only shows "connected to the target virtual machine".

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause:
You can put dubug point only that location where it shows you true (Right) mark.Cross is the idication that you have put it in wrong place

Comment: the debugger is not attaching bro..no issues with color

Comment: I am not talking about color...When you put debug point on perticular line then that point will have one of the sign whether it is cross or right.Make sure it has right indication

Comment: Its a red circle

Comment: in this red circle one of those two indicator will be shown.
Do one thing run your project
click on icon left of red square(stop) on top baar.
click ok
then do debugging

Comment: It is running with debug mode but the debugger is not attached...the app is running on my mi max phone